# Shaders with pygtkglext

Tags: python, pygtk, glsl, shader

Do someone know how to get glsl shaders work in gtk-opengl window? With glut all `glCreateProgram` etc. functions works, but when I tried to put the same gl code into pygtkglext window, its complaining about NullReference:

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glCreateProgram, check for bool(glCreateProgram) before calling
```

So then I `from OpenGL.GL.ARB.shader_objects import *`, but the result is similar:

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glCreateProgramObjectARB, check for bool(glCreateProgramObjectARB) before calling
```

Any idea will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is its not supported yet. Simply pygtkglext doesn't set glCreateProgram. However git version does.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL entry points are obtained using GetProcAddress routine. I suppose the NULL pointer is the function pointer glCreateProgramObjectARB.

This is strictly related with libraries installed with the driver. Which OpenGL version is running on the host? Maybe the driver doesn't implements the glCreateProgramObjectARB.

Comment: The answer is `its not supported yet`. Simply pygtkglext doesn't set `glCreateProgram`. However git version does.